# Flexslider: How to loop specific number of times?

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I want to loop slides specific number of times and stop on the last slide.

Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 5000});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in a while loop? perhaps you could add more code or an example?

    var i = 0;

    while (i <= 9)
    {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 5000});

     i++;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the callback features you could do something like this.

First set a variable to the number of loops you want:

`var n = 4`

then when you initialise the slider add this option:

```
after: function(slider) {
   if (slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1) { // is last slide
      n--;
      if(n==0) {
        slider.pause();
      }
   }
}
```

I had hoped to use the `end: function(){}` feature but this only fires when the animation is disabled.
There is a slight annoyance here as the `var n` will continue to decrement if the users cycle manually. Not too troublesome though I hope.

A nice bonus here is that you can resume the slideshow if you want. Check out the [advanced docs](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/#tabs-flexslider-info-tabber-tab-2) for more.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This does not work. Gives missing }); after property list. $(document).ready(function() {
 var n = 2;
 $('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshowSpeed: 5000, after: function(slider) {
  if (slider.currentSlide == slider.count - 1) { // is last slide
   n--;
   if (n==0) { slider.pause(); }
  }
 });
});

Comment: Looks like you forgot to close the function with }. Works fine.

Comment: bleh bad indentation messed up my closure. that should work. *EDIT* I've updated the answer with the correct closure, glad it's working :)